# Add rows in Datagridview in ascending order

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I am currently using Datagridview.rows.Add to add rows to my DatagridView.

Is there a way to have the data add in ascending order?

I do not want a button to do so, rather to add all data in ascending order by default.  I didn't see a way in the properties.

Note: the Reason I'm doing this is so users would not have to stroll down to look at the current data.  The old data will be at the bottom of the datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Insert Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows(v=vs.110).aspx) of DataGridView.

```
DGV.Rows.Insert(0, {"One", "Two", "Three"})
```